# Overlapping yticklabels: Is it possible to control cell size of heatmap in seaborn?

Tags: python, matplotlib, heatmap, axis-labels, seaborn

I have a dataset with around 200 observations which I would like to plot as a heatmap. Each observation has a string associated with it which I would like to display. My problem is that I cannot read these labels since they overlap each other. My question is therefore, whether one can somehow set the cell size of the heatmap to the font size of the `yticklabel` or whether there is any other workaround for that.

In my example below, I use random data for illustration purposes:

```
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
data = np.random.rand(200, 10)
ax = sns.heatmap(data)
for item in ax.get_yticklabels():
    item.set_rotation(0)
```

which gives me:

[image]

Is there a way to make these `yticklabels` readable? In the ideal case, I would have an option that allows me to set the cells' height to the fontsize of the `yticklabels`. Is that possible?

EDIT:

As mentioned in the comments, one possibility would be to increase the figure's size. I tried that as follows:

```
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.random.rand(200, 10)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.set_size_inches(38.5, 10.5)

ax2 = sns.heatmap(data, ax=ax)
for item in ax2.get_yticklabels():
    item.set_rotation(0)
```

This gives me the same output. Am I using it correctly?

Comment: Is it possible to only print 1 out of 5 or 10?

Comment: No, I would like to have all of them displayed which makes it tricky, I think.

Comment: you could cut it in half, and plot one half on the right side, one half on the other side ?

Comment: But how do I then know which label belongs to which row? In the ideal world, I would have an option that says: `cellheight = seizeOfYticklabel`

Comment: If you want all these labels to be visible, you clearly need more space. Have you tried to simply increase the figure height?

Comment: @hitzg: Yes, I tried but it did not seem to affect the output. I will add my attempts to the question. How would you do it?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The only way to make more room for the labels is to increase the height of the matrix. The only other option would be to decrease the font size, but I guess that's not what you want.
So you can compute the ideal figure height based on the number of rows in the matrix and the font size of the labels. When you save the resulting plot you get the expected result. It seems that the height of the GUI window which you see when calling `plt.show()` is limited to the screen height:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

# create some random data
data = np.random.rand(150, 10)

# get the tick label font size
fontsize_pt = plt.rcParams['ytick.labelsize']
dpi = 72.27

# comput the matrix height in points and inches
matrix_height_pt = fontsize_pt * data.shape[0]
matrix_height_in = matrix_height_pt / dpi

# compute the required figure height 
top_margin = 0.04  # in percentage of the figure height
bottom_margin = 0.04 # in percentage of the figure height
figure_height = matrix_height_in / (1 - top_margin - bottom_margin)


# build the figure instance with the desired height
fig, ax = plt.subplots(
        figsize=(6,figure_height), 
        gridspec_kw=dict(top=1-top_margin, bottom=bottom_margin))

# let seaborn do it's thing
ax = sns.heatmap(data, ax=ax)

# save the figure
plt.savefig('/tmp/test.png')
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Fantastic! Exactly what I was looking for! I upvote it now and might accept it later on, depending on other answers' quality. Edit: You might also want to add the way you rotate the `yticklabels` to your code.

Comment: Glad I could help. In your example you set the rotation to 0, which is the default (and thus setting it doesn't really do anything). 
Measuring the text height of a rotated text object, will be a lot more difficult, as it depends on further things such as the font family...

Comment: Then we might have different versions of `seaborn`. I need the rotation=0 to get the horizontal output, it seems.

Comment: yep, it seems so. I don't use it often so I might have an outdated version (0.7.dev)...
Btw: pyplot provides a convinience function to set properties on multiple artists, which you could use to make setting the rotation a bit more compact:
`plt.setp(ax.get_yticklabels(), 'rotation', 0)`

Comment: Oh, that is good to know, thanks! Unfortunately, I can upvote only once ;)

Comment: @hitzg Thank you for your helpful answer. I have tried to replicate your suggested solution to a larger confusion matrix (`66x66`) and couldn't get it to display annotations in the cells nicely. Could you please check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51144934/1330974) that I posted and see if you could help? Thank you!