# How do I change the size of the plot and prevent overlapping in the y axis?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, graph

I have plotted a horizontal bar graph with a large number of horizontal bars.
Is there any way I could prevent the **overlapping of the y axis titles and the bars in the bar graphs**. Or the only way is increasing the height of the graph?
I have tried using: 
*plt.figure(figsize=(13,14))* but it doesn't work also when I try replacing *plt.show()* by *plt.figure(figsize=(13,14)).show()*

I get the error :
*UserWarning: matplotlib is currently using a non-GUI backend, so cannot show the figure*
  "matplotlib is currently using a non-GUI backend, "

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcdefaults()
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

length=[477, 531, 568, 651, 1599, 1605, 1635, 1960, 2009, 2446, 2668, 3308, 3433, 3889, 4180, 4529, 5388, 6378, 7588, 7671, 7679, 8505, 8763, 8863, 8910, 9028, 9030, 10124, 10722, 10894, 11103, 11388, 12167, 12464, 14217, 14367, 14472, 16501, 18765, 19407, 19627, 20795, 21727, 21912, 22620, 24871, 25045, 25625, 25867, 27512, 30380, 30424, 31264, 32070, 32277, 33879, 35749, 35932, 37406, 37414, 40040, 42070, 42516, 42804, 44381, 46314, 48216, 48349, 50547, 50796, 53759, 54716, 65888, 81106, 86280, 104522, 179133, 189921]
y_pos = np.arange(len(length))
error = np.random.rand(len(length))
plt.barh(y_pos, length, xerr=error*2, align='center', alpha=0.3)
plt.yticks(y_pos, length)
plt.xlabel('Lengths')
plt.title('Comparison of different cuts')
plt.show()
```

This is the graph I am referring to:

[image]

Comment: I managed to do this using this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35127920/overlapping-yticklabels-is-it-possible-to-control-cell-size-of-heatmap-in-seabo

Answer (score 3):

You are plotting a very large amount of bars in a small space and labeling each tick mark. The easiest way to make this legible is with increasing the length of the plot. Using `plt.figure(figsize=(10,20))` instantly makes the plot legible for me.

If you want to keep the figure the same size, you have a few other knobs to tweak. First you can control the height of each horizontal bar with the `height` parameter. It defaults to .8 so try using a lower value. You can also control the size of the yticks with the `fontsize` parameter. Tweaking these parameters will give you non-overlapping bars/ticks but at a cost of resolution. To increase the resolution upon saving your figure with `plt.savefig`, use the `dpi` parameter to set it higher than the default.

Comment: As mentioned before, I tried using  *plt.figure(figsize=(13,14))* but somehow didn't work for me. It would be great if you **edit the code mentioned and provide the picture of the plot you obtain** on making the relevant changes. Thanks in advance I

Comment: Please mention the code that helped you get this to work with the code above.

Answer (score 0):

The number of labels on the y-axis is quite high, so it will be hard to get them all to fit within a plot. Increasing the size of the plot will help, and another thing that might help, is to decrease the font size of the y-tick labels like this:

```
ax = plt.gca()
for tick in ax.yaxis.get_major_ticks():
    tick.label.set_fontsize(6)
```

Maybe you could also just give every other, or third y-tick label.