# Seaborn heatmap reducing cell size

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, heatmap

Is there any way to change cell size of Seaborn heatmap?
I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35127920/overlapping-yticklabels-is-it-possible-to-control-cell-size-of-heatmap-in-seabo) but I cannot get it work as expected.

So, I have long text in y-axis labels. Since all of the texts are chopped off, I would like to shrink cell size of the heatmap much smaller. I don't need that big rectangle. (Highlighted just for example.)

[image]
(I hid label names.)

When I change the figure size by something like,

```
plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6)) or 
figure.set_size_inches(12, 12)
```

the cell gets bigger as well so the texts remain chopped off.

Here is the code.

```
sns.set(font_scale=1.2)
ax0 = plt.axes()
ax1 = sns.heatmap(hmap, cbar=0, cmap="YlGnBu",linewidths=2, ax=ax0,vmax=3000, vmin=0)
ax1.set_title('test heatmap')

for item in ax1.get_yticklabels():
    item.set_rotation(0)

for item in ax1.get_xticklabels():
    item.set_rotation(0)

figure = plt.gcf()  # get current figure
figure.set_size_inches(12, 12)
plt.savefig('test.png') , dpi=400)
```

Comment: there's no point in doing: `ax0 = plt.axes()` if you're not going to pass the axes to `heatmap`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try using the `square=True` argument in your `sns.heatmap` call. This will constrain the heat map cells to a square aspect ratio.

```
ax1 = sns.heatmap(hmap, cbar=0, cmap="YlGnBu",linewidths=2, ax=ax0,vmax=3000, vmin=0, square=True)
```

Answer (score 7):

You don't actually want to change the cell size but you want to shrink the size of the axes. Ways to to this:

- use `plt.tight_layout()`
- Provide more space to the side e.g. via `fig.subplots_adjust(left=0.4)`
- Create an axes, which has the size you want, `ax1 = fig.add_axes([0.4,0.2,0.5,0.6])` (where the numbers are `[left, bottom, width, height]` and use this axes to plot the heatmap, `sns.heatmap(... , ax=ax1)`.