# Set a minimum tile size for seaborn heatmap

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, size, heatmap

Using seaborn and matplotlib.pyplot in python is there a way to enforce a minimum/maximum size for the tiles in a heatmap?

I want to show the annotated values inside the tiles, but for more than a 9-10 samples the tiles become too small for the text. I dont want to set a fixed larger figure size to increase the tile size, since its not a one-time graph and I dont know how many samples will need to be displayed each time.

```
#graph plotting part
rcParams.update({"figure.constrained_layout.use": True})
ax = seaborn.heatmap(plotdata, cmap=seaborn.color_palette("flare", as_cmap=True), annot=True, linewidths=.5, fmt=".2f")
plt.show(ax)
```

Leads to:

[image: Heatmap tiles to small for annotation]

Comment: Things you can try:  setting a smaller font size for the heatmap annotations and/or the tick labels.  Also, you could shorten the ticks to have more room for the heatmap (e.g. leaving out the `.bam` and placing a newline before `LR` to have the labels on two lines. You can also set a small negative `pad` for the colorbar to have it closer to the heatmap.  Forcing a minimum tile size seems counterproductive: someone needs to decide where the extra space should come from, better you are that someone.

Comment: @JohanC I had hoped there would be a solution for the figure size to expand automatically to account for the required minimum size of the plotting area. For now it seems my best bet is to scale the total figure size by number of samples (similar to here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35127920/overlapping-yticklabels-is-it-possible-to-control-cell-size-of-heatmap-in-seabo) to plot and somehow fidget with Dividers to give this additional space to the plot area only. (at the moment its evenly spread to labels and tiles i think) - though this seems to become quiet a hassle

Comment: If you call `plt.tight_layout()` afterwards, the space for the labels will be adjusted to fit everything with some minimal padding.